# Position images automatically when retrieving images from database by using bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I retrieve images from a database in a `Image` element.

The problem is the retrieved images are not mobile responsive and I want to make those retrieved images mobile responsive. When a user opens the website on mobile the images must go underneath each other and display nicely.

I tried using bootstrap but the images do not go underneath each other when the website is opened on a mobile device

This is what I have:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4  " style="text-align: center;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Logo")) %>' />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

--

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * from [dbo].[tb_Stores]", con);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command); DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dtEmployees);

DataList1.DataSource = dtEmployees;

DataList1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Please assist me how I can make all images retrieved mobile responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you cannot use older ASP.NET controls like, Repeater, DataList, DataGrid, GridView, FormView in Responsive Design as they automatically create a table. Try using a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Next, try applying `class="img-responsive"` to your images as described in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images-responsive).

This class mainly applies the styles max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to fit the containing element, otherwise if an image width is larger than the parent element's width it may overflow and break your layout.

Also, remove the fixed sizes from the images and control this by the %size of the containing elements. There are no fixed sizes in RWD.

Comment: I used a ListView. Thank you